# Which soft is the best choice for the Fortran project?

Tags: fortran

I have to compile [this](https://github.com/davidhoover/DNAWorks) project based on Fortran. I am new in Fortran, so what compiler or IDE could you recommend to build this project? I tried to use Codeblocks, but it has many problems with libraries and compiler versions. What is the .f90 and .inp file formats? Which soft can read both? I use Windows 10.

Comment: Do you prefer command line or GUI? What OS do you use? What is your budget?

Comment: I think GUI is more convenient as this project has many files. I use Windows 10.

Comment: And then it will be unheld and you will hopefully get an answer